# how to go to function directory in firebase cloud function in command prompt

Tags: node.js, shell, firebase, google-cloud-functions

this is my command prompt

[image]

I have done it by using tutorial in that tutorial

```
ls -la
```

is used. But when I use that its not working.

this is his code image
[image]

Comment: Most of us Firebasers use Mac OSX for screencasts, including what Jen did in that video.  You'll have to convert what she does there into the appropriate windows shell commands.  So if you want to see the files in a directory, try `dir`.  Changing directory is still `cd`.

Comment: how can i use shell commands in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enter the function directory you can simply `cd (change directory)` into it like so `cd functions`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -la
```

does not work on Windows.  Install Bash shell and try again

Answer (score 0):

What I think is very easy, open terminal, type cd and than search your map where the functions contains. After you found the map, click on that map and hold it, and drag it onto your terminal. Than, you have the full directory easy.

Edit: O you are on Windows hehe, above is for Mac. Sorry.